# initiateCall option not working on blackberry device

Tags: blackberry

I've used below code for call option when use hit ok button.

it working on simulator and goes to calling option, but when i check on device nothg happn. my device model is 9800.

```
String[] buttons = { "CALL" ,"CANCEL" };
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Are you sure want to call "+number+" ?", buttons, null, 1, Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.INFORMATION));
        if (dialog.doModal() == 0) 
        {
            try 
            {
                String numbers = StringUtils.replaceAll(number, "-", "");
                Phone.initiateCall(Phone.getLineIds()[0],numbers);
            }
            catch (RadioException e) 
            {
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
PhoneArguments callArgs = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL,numbers);
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, callArgs);
```